# Sending a SMS in app through MessageUI

Tags: ios, messageui

Please help to solve the issue of sending invites to the app via SMS or iMessage.

The issue is that when all the receipents of the message have iMessage available (blue button), then upon invitation sending a group consisting of these people gets created, but I need to send the messages separately (not in group).

```
if MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText() {
        let messageViewController = MFMessageComposeViewController()

        messageViewController.body = "Some invite text"
        messageViewController.recipients = [phone_numbers_from_contacts]
        messageViewController.messageComposeDelegate = self

        self.present(messageViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        // Some alert with text "SMS services are not available"
    }
```

Comment: that's a little hard to understand

Comment: good point @Fogmeister  :)

Comment: In my app. I want send invites in my app through MessageUI with my text.

Comment: Can you include the code that you are using.

Comment: @Fogmeister I want to send an individual message to each of the recipients.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you have no control over whether the message is sent as a group message or not.

If you want to send it as individual messages then I would suggest using multiple different instances of the `MFMessageComposeViewController`.

TBH though, you shouldn't really be using this for sending out spam texts anyway.

Comment: Thanks for help, but is better to leave the field with recipients empty.